# PHPExcel ошибка communication failure

Tags: php, phpexcel

Как в phpexcel можно сослаться на определенный лист, чтобы использовать в формуле данные с него   =СУММ('Part2'!P25:P29), то есть 'Part2'
заменить?

```
      <?php

    //Подключаем библиотеку
    require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
    require_once 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php';

    //создаем объект PHPExcel
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    //Открываем файл-шаблон
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly( array("Part2","Part11") );
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('C:\rkm\apps\wp\projects\openschool\scripts\od1pr1.xls');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // Получаем активный лист 
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $sheet->setCellValue('P25', 11);
    $sheet->setCellValue('P26', 13);
    $sheet->setCellValue('P27', 18);
    $sheet->setCellValue('P28', 33);
    $sheet->setCellValue('P29', 6);

    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1);

    $formula0 = '=SUM(\'Part1\'!P25:P29)'; 
    $sheet->setCellValue('P25', $formula0 );

    // Если запрос аяксом - значит нужно вывести html отчёт, иначе - нужно отдать excel файл для скачивания
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_HTML($objPHPExcel);
            $objWriter->writeAllSheets();
            //$objWriter->setSheetIndex(2);;
    }else{
        // Выводим HTTP-заголовки
        header ( "Expires: Mon, 1 Apr 1974 05:00:00 GMT" );
        header ( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT" );
        header ( "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
        header ( "Pragma: no-cache" );
        header ( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
        header ( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=department.xls" );
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);
    }

    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: попробуйте удалять по одной формуле (или наоборот - удалить все и по одной добавлять). Возможно проблема в какой-то одной формуле.... Если найдете формулу - попроббуйте её упростить, чтобы понять, какая часть формулы дает ошибку, а позже поправите вопрос (если сами не поймёте) - тогда уже будет конкретная тема для решения

Comment: как я понял, проблема в формулах с ссылками на другие листы, но я не знаю почему это происходит. Уже сидел, там такую одну оставишь и уже не читается.

Comment: попробуйте для эксперимента назвать листы одним англ.словом типа part1 (чтобы исключить проблемы кирилицы)

Comment: Тоже пробовал, но ничего не поменялось

Comment: Теперь точно уверен, что ошибка получается из за обращение к ячейке с другого листа     =СУММ('Part2'!P25:P29). Формула записывается на Part11.

Comment: попробуйте просто 'Part2'!P25 + 'Part2'!P26 например... если сработает, то можно будет расчёты сложных формул производить на одном листе и записывать в определенную ячейку, а простыми операциями связывать листы..... у меня были расчёты на разных листах,  вроде всё нормально было... сейчас нет возможности проверить...

Comment: Пара тестов, и я все таки ошибся, походу влияет название листов, надо их латиницей называть, но беда в том, что мне нельзя поменять название.

Comment: Еще тесты, оказалось влияет вложенная СУММ в ЕСЛИ, то есть надо расписать СУММ как сложение ячеек, то есть СУММ(х1:xn) поменять на x1+x2+...+xn, но опять же, мне ничего нельзя в шаблоне менять

Comment: могу посоветовать во первых, проверить последняя ли версия библиотеки, во вторых - библиотека с открытым исходным кодом, поэтому вы можете переопределить некоторые моменты (сделать надстройку для подготовки перед импортом), например, поменять при импорте программно в формулах вместо названий листов использовать их индексы....

Comment: можете задать новые вопросы но уже конкретно к ситуациям (как использовать русски название листов, так как нет возможности поменять; использование вложенных функции и т.д.) - вы скорее получите ответы на конкретные мелкие вопросы, чем на один большой

Comment: возможно посмотрите на альтернативы phpexcel